# Detecting touch events on UILabel

Tags: uigesturerecognizer

I have a UILabel that I am adding programmatically to my main view. I then add a gesture recognizer to get touch events on the label:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recog = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTouchNotification)];
[notification addGestureRecognizer:recog];
[recog release];
```

However, nothing fires when the label is touched. I logged all subviews to make sure the label was on top, and it is. The only way I can get the recognizer to work is if I add it to the underlying view, but that isn't much help. Does anyone know why this label is behaving so "transparently"?

Happy holidays!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`UILabel` has its `userInteractionEnabled` property set to `NO` by default so it does not receive touch events and gesture recognizer does not work. Try to enable user interaction for your label:

```
...
notification.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
...
```